# Multiple Clients in Client Server app in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, client-server

using resources at http://www.developerfusion.com  i came up with the following server code. It works well for single client. How can i make it for multiple clients. I tried adding array and different instances of the beiginreceive but was unable to. The server code:

```
class Program
{
    public static AsyncCallback pfnWorkerCallBack;
    public static Socket m_socListener;
    public static Socket m_socWorker;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //create the listening socket...
            m_socListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8221);
            //bind to local IP Address...
            m_socListener.Bind(ipLocal);
            Console.WriteLine("UCManager Started");
            //start listening...
            m_socListener.Listen(4);
            // create the call back for any client connections...
            m_socListener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {
            m_socWorker = m_socListener.EndAccept(asyn);

            WaitForData(m_socWorker);
        }
        catch (Exception se)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
        }

    }
    public class CSocketPacket
    {
        public System.Net.Sockets.Socket thisSocket;
        public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1];
    }

    public static void WaitForData(System.Net.Sockets.Socket soc)
    {
        try
        {
            if (pfnWorkerCallBack == null)
            {
                pfnWorkerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
            }
            CSocketPacket theSocPkt = new CSocketPacket();
            theSocPkt.thisSocket = soc;
            // now start to listen for any data...
            soc.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0, theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, pfnWorkerCallBack, theSocPkt);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
        }

    }

    public static void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {
            CSocketPacket theSockId = (CSocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
            //end receive...
            int iRx = 0;
            iRx = theSockId.thisSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
            char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
            Decoder d = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            int charLen = d.GetChars(theSockId.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
            String szData = new String(chars);
            Console.WriteLine(szData);
            int code = Convert.ToInt32(szData); 

            WaitForData(m_socWorker);
        }

        catch (Exception se)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

}

EDIT: Ok i did something on the lines of [Async TCP Server for multiple Clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796836/async-tcp-server-for-multiple-clients).

```
public static void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket m_socWorkerInstance = m_socListener.EndAccept(asyn);
                clientSocketList.Add(m_socWorkerInstance);

                WaitForData(m_socWorkerInstance);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\n OnClientConnection: Socket has been closed\n");
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
            }

        }
public static void WaitForData(System.Net.Sockets.Socket soc)
        {
            try
            {
                if (pfnWorkerCallBack == null)
                {
                    pfnWorkerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
                }
                CSocketPacket theSocPkt = new CSocketPacket();
                theSocPkt.thisSocket = soc;
                // now start to listen for any data...
                soc.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0, theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, pfnWorkerCallBack, theSocPkt);
                m_socListener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
            }

        }
```

**Now i am able to connect two clients but not able to communicate ...I am unable to send message from server to client...any suggestions...also should i have different read functions for both clients if i connect with two client???**

Comment: Using multiple threads is exactly what you need. Why don't you want threads?

Comment: i was lookingmore on the lines of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796836/async-tcp-server-for-multiple-clients   but i am unable to implement this in my code

Comment: **One more thing...can i know from which client i am receiving the message...if the server receives a message from A then it should send some notification to client B and if it receives from B it should send some notification to A. That was the reason why i asked if i would read different read functions**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i was able to solve it using  [Async TCP Server for multiple Clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796836/async-tcp-server-for-multiple-clients):

```
public static void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
            {
                try
                {
                    Socket m_socWorkerInstance = m_socListener.EndAccept(asyn);
                    clientSocketList.Add(m_socWorkerInstance);

                    WaitForData(m_socWorkerInstance);
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\n OnClientConnection: Socket has been closed\n");
                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
                }

            }
    public static void WaitForData(System.Net.Sockets.Socket soc)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (pfnWorkerCallBack == null)
                    {
                        pfnWorkerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
                    }
                    CSocketPacket theSocPkt = new CSocketPacket();
                    theSocPkt.thisSocket = soc;
                    // now start to listen for any data...
                    soc.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0, theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, pfnWorkerCallBack, theSocPkt);
                    m_socListener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You call `BeginAccept` only once, so after one client has been accepted, your server won't accept any new connections. You should call `BeginAccept` again after accepting a connection.

Comment: i tried something...please have a look at the edited question

Comment: @kewal _"But now the server sort of hangs up"_ - I can't do anything with that.

Comment: haha...ofcourse you cant, it was because of something else...thanks for the suggestion though